# parsing JSON with a nested, dynamic type

Tags: json, flutter, dart, dynamic

Let's assume I have 3 data classes (which in reality may be many more). Class `A` **or** class `B` shall be wrapped in class `Wrap` with a data type identifier. This shall allow using the same process inside the app for any data type provided by the json interface.

```dart
class Wrap{
  int id;
  List<dynamic> dataSet;
  Wrap({required this.id, required this.dataSet});
}

class A{
  int a=0;
  A({this.a});
}

class B{
  bool b=true;
  B({this.b});
}
```

My aim was to use a map `getDataType = {0: A, 1: B};` and then to parse the nested Json with

```dart
dataSets: List<dynamic>.from(json["dataSets"].map((d) => getDataType[json["id"].fromJson(d)).toList();
```

But unfortunately this already fails when trying to access a class method from the variable containing the type

```dart
class A{
  int i=0; A({i});
  factory A.test(int i) => A(2*i); 
}

main() {
  final t = A;
  final x = t.test(2);
}
```

Anyone with a smart idea how to achieve this?

The rational behind this unorthodox data structure is: I have a data manager in the business logic layer that triggers different UIs depending on some events, coming from a different logic. The manager then fetches the specific data for the UI. To streamline this, the same repository with the same functions shall be used. However, the repository function uses a different database table depending on the UI.

UPDATE: Most basic example json:

```json
{
 "id": 0,
  "data": [ 
    {
      "problemId": 0,
      "level": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add the template json you are trying to parse

Comment: done as an update to the question. Thanks

Comment: Check out this answer on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57661860/6704033

Comment: That one is different, it has a constant data structure - unless I miss something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create an abstact class for datasets

```
abstract class Dataset {
  const Dataset();
  factory Dataset.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, int type) {
    switch (type) {
      case 0:
        return ADataset.fromMap(map);
      case 1:
        return BDataset.fromMap(map);
      default:
        throw Exception("Class with id $type couldn't be found");
    }
  }
}
```

and replace `List<dynamic> dataSet;` in `Wrap` class with  `List<Dataset> dataSet;`

Now you can simply create dataset classes by extending this `Dataset` class

```
class ADataset extends Dataset {
  final int fieldA;
  ADataset(
    this.fieldA,
  );
  factory ADataset.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ADataset(map['int field']);
  }
}

class BDataset extends Dataset {
  final String fieldB;
  BDataset(
    this.fieldB,
  );
  factory BDataset.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return BDataset(map['string field']);
  }
}
```

So now all you need to do is

```
dataSets: List<Dataset>.from(map['datasets'].map(
    (dataset) => Dataset.fromMap(dataset, map['type']),
  ));
```

Comment: That looks really promising. Thanks a lot. I have one issue, though. My data class is already abstract since I am using the freezed package for class comparison etc. As such, my class definition looks like this because of freezed : `@freezed
abstract class ProblemsDto implements _$ProblemsDto {` Can I use your method somehow with `mixin`? I know, mixin exists, but haven't used it yet.

Comment: @w461 not really, mixins cannot be used for implementing constructors.

Comment: can you make subclasses `@freezed` and not the interface

Comment: I am in the middle of refactoring this without freezed, wasn't of much value for those kind of classes, anyways. Thanks again!

Comment: sorry, one more thing: any idea how to do it vice versa (toJson)? If you have `Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {id: id, datasets: datasets.map((s) => s.toDomain()).toList()` in the `Wrap` class, it requires obviously a toJson function in the class `Dataset`. But doesn't this require all fields of all A/BDataset classes to be in `Dataset`? Or is there some other elegant way?

Comment: add a `Map<String, dynamic> toJson();` to the abstract Dataset class and override it in subclasses. then you can convert datasets the way you mentioned and I think it's an elegant way. @w461